# jquery (1.8.2) data selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes

I'm using jQuery 1.8.2

I put a data on the element with:

```
el.data('uid', 'value')
```

How can I find the element with this data? I tried selectors

```
$('.class-name:data(uid="value")')
$('.class-name[uid="value"]')
```

But it doesn't work, is there a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use selectors, you'll want to use `.attr()` and set a `data-` attribute.

```
// set data
$('p').attr('data-uid', 1234);

// find by uid
$('p[data-uid=1234]');

// find all with data-uid
$('[data-uid]')
```

[See some examples here](http://jsfiddle.net/BzYjX/)

Comment: Yes, thanks, that is what I did -) But I was sure that data selector is supported out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `filter` method:

```
$('.selector').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('uid') === 'value';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After searching the documentation, it seems the jquery selector `:data()` is not in jQuery itself but in jQuery UI's Core.
You can find the documentation here : http://api.jqueryui.com/category/ui-core/

Comment: Thanks I was sure that data selector is supported out of the box by jquery core.

Comment: Yeah I thought so too, but after a fiew google search I found it was in jQuery UI. In Chrome I was seeing JS errors when trying :data() with only jQuery.